# como lograr que la lista se muestre con un efecto de transicion?

Tags: angular, lista, responsive, navbar, transicion

estoy haciendo un menu de navegación responsive, que se despliega lateralmente (esto ya lo hice con una transición), pero el problema es que dentro de este menu tengo una lista, que quiero que muestre con un efecto o una transicion vertical, pero por mas sencillo que parezca no puedo hacerlo funcionar, solo quiero que al hacer lick en `Secciones` esta lista se muestre con un efecto tipo `toggle` y no bruscamente como esta actualmente.

este es parte del código:

```html
  <div class="menuMovil">  
    <div 
      class="text-left cursor-pointer pl-2 pt-1 pb-1 d-flex flex-column align-items-start"  
      (click)="ocultarSecciones= !ocultarSecciones">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <mat-icon class="iconosMovil">category</mat-icon>
        <span class="ml-2 text-white">Secciones</span>
      </div>
      <div class="secciones color-grey" [ngClass]="{'ocultarSecciones': ocultarSecciones}">
        <ul class="options">
          <li class="option" [routerLink]="['/marketplacePrincipal']"> Marketplace</li>
          <li class="option" [routerLink]="['/emprendedores']"> Emprendedores</li>
          <li class="option" [routerLink]="['/nosotros']">Nosotros</li>
          <li class="option" [routerLink]="['/ver-blogs']">Blog</li>
          <li class="option" [routerLink]="['/contacto']">Contacto</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>    
 </div>
```

en el .css actualmente tengo esto:

```css
.secciones .options{
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  outline: none;
}

.secciones.ocultarSecciones .options{
  display: block;
}
```

el contenedor padre (menuMovil) está con position: fixed, por si eso influye en algo.

intenté colocar una altura de 0px a la lista, y que en la transición obtuviera su altura, algo como muestran en la respuesta a esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css/20226830#20226830) pero no se por que no desaprece, la altura es 0 pero la lista se muestra, sinceramente no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Estoy trabajando con Angular, pero estoy haciendo esto con html y css puro, sin javascript o typescript.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

No te compliques la vida, usa una librería llamada [`ng-material-multilevel-menu`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu), es mas profesional, mas limpio.

```sh
npm install --save ng-material-multilevel-menu
```

```
///Componente
menuItems= [
   {
      label: 'Secciones',
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Marketplace',
          link: '/marketplacePrincipal',
        },
        {
          label: 'Emprendedores',
          link: '/emprendedores',
        },
        {
          label: 'Nosotros',
          link: '/nosotros',
        },
        {
          label: 'Blog',
          link: '/ver-blog',
        },
       {
          label: 'Contacto',
          link: '/contacto',
        }
      ]
    },
]
```

```html
<!--html-->
<ng-material-multilevel-menu [items]='menuItems'></ng-material-multilevel-menu>
```